# React - how to prevent a function from being called at short intervals

Tags: reactjs

I have a function that should not be called many times over a short period of time (eg 1 second). My function should be called at least every 2 seconds. For example function `setNextPage()` should be called immediately and then after at least 2 seconds. I want to prevent calling function `setNextPage` or `setPrevPage` for example 5 times in a second. How to do that?

My function

```
 <Scheduler
    onMouseMove={handleMouseMove}
 />


const handleMouseMove = (event: any) => {
            if (dragMode) { // code should be called only when starting a drag mode
                setDragMode(false);
                const bounds = event.currentTarget.getBoundingClientRect();
                const xPosition = event.clientX - bounds.left;
                if (
                    xPosition >
                    calendarContainerRef?.current?.clientWidth - 20
                ) {
                    setNextPage(); //this function should be called not more often than every 2 seconds
                }
                if (xPosition < 90) {
                    setPrevPage(); //this function should be called not more often than every 2 seconds
                }
            }
        };
```

Comment: Google how to throttle or debounce

Comment: What do you mean atleast? Is there a fixed interval you want, or is it if the function were to be invoked multiple times in a second you want to deny it from executing?

Comment: I want to prevent calling function setNextPage or setPrevPage for example 5 times in a second

Comment: You want to use throttle or debounce. Here's an article on how to do that with lodash and a react hook: https://nodeployfriday.com/posts/react-debounce/